# Filemaker: Copy Global Variable from a Related Table?

Tags: copy, global-variables, relational-database, filemaker

I have a parent table that contains a global variable named gStartDate.

In a child table I have placed a global variable with the identical name. It has a calculated value:

```
ParentTable::gStartDate
```

However, it appears that it never copies the date from ParentTable::gStartDate.  How can I correct this?

Thanks in advance to all for any info.

Comment: Are you sure gStartDate is set as global in the field definition? This should work even if the tables are not related and regardless of whether gStartDate in the child table is global. Note: You are working with a Global Field. Global Variables are something completely different. Be careful with your terminology.

Comment: Yes. In Manage Database->Fields tab, the field is listed as "gStartDate - Date - Global".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its sounds like you set the calculated field in the child table to use "global" storage.  That isn't going to update unless you update the schema or create a new record in the child table.

What you want is to set the calculated field to in the child table to be "un-stored".  That will update when it is needed. And when it does it will pull the correct result from the parent table.

See the image.[image: dialog showing the correct setting]